# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: when trying to write workbook to desktop

Tags: python, permissions, permission-denied

My code is below:

```
from openpyxl import *

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
ws.title = "primes"

prime_list = find_primes_to(1000)

index = 0
while index < prime_list.__len__():
    ws.cell( row = index + 1, column = 1, value = prime_list[index])
    index += 1

print("almost done")

wb.close()
wb.save('C:/Users/David/Desktop')

print("done")
```

Everything up to the "wb.save()" seems to be working properly, and if I run it without the path it executes just fine (though I can't find where it saves to). Adding the path throws this as an output:

```
almost done
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/David/PycharmProjects/Primes/Primes runner.py", line 62, in <module>
    wb.save('C:/Users/David/Desktop')
  File "C:\Users\David\PycharmProjects\Primes\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line 372, in save
    save_workbook(self, filename)
  File "C:\Users\David\PycharmProjects\Primes\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 282, in save_workbook
    archive = ZipFile(filename, 'w', ZIP_DEFLATED, allowZip64=True)
  File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\zipfile.py", line 1090, in __init__
    self.fp = io.open(file, filemode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:/Users/David/Desktop'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I've checked the error code. I've tried running it as admin, I've tried running saving it to different file locations. I've tried saving it to different drives, even external flash drives. I cann't figure out how to get the proper permissions. Any suggestions?

EDIT: Alright I solved it. In order to save it you have to add add an actual file name to the end of the path like so: 'C:/Users/David/Desktop/test.xlsx'.
This will create the new file

Comment: Do you have the file open in an editor?

Answer (score 7):

I had the same error....but looks like i had the output file open in the background.I closed it and the program worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write to a FILE.  For example:
wb.close()
wb.save('C:/Users/David/Desktop/Hello.xlsx')
or
wb.save(r'C:\Users\David\Desktop\Hello.xlsx')

This will also occur when you attempt to write to an excel file while that file is currently open.